# python Sqlite3 parameter subs

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a small problem with this class which handle my DB. It still saying:

```
 cursor.execute(sql)
 ValueError: operation parameter must be str
```

I tried lots of things but nothing work as i want. I looked over https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sqlite3.html  and i'm sure i do the same things.

```
import sqlite3

class Database():

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.db = sqlite3.connect('../database.sqlite')
            self.cur = self.db.cursor()
            self.cur.execute('pragma foreign_keys="1"')
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            raise e

    def select(self,sql):

        cursor = self.db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql)
        records = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        return records

    def insert(self,sql):

        cursor = self.db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql)
        newID = cursor.lastrowid
        self.db.commit()
        cursor.close()
        return newID

    def execute(self,sql):
    """ execute any SQL statement but no return value given """

        cursor = self.db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql)
        self.db.commit()
        cursor.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
db = Database()
#sql = "SELECT skuref, titre_prod FROM product"
t = ("888888",)
sql= "UPDATE product SET created = 1 WHERE skuref = ?", t
db.execute(sql)
```

If someone can help me it would be grateful.Later i wanted to pass something like this in the main program inside a for loop

```
lastpost = record[0]
if created = True
sql = "UPDATE product SET created = 1 WHERE skuref = ?",(lastpost,)                
db.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sql` is a tuple containing SQL statement and the parameters.

Change as following, so that sql and parameters are passed separately, instead of being passed as a tuple:

```
def execute(self, sql):
    """ execute any SQL statement but no return value given """
    cursor = self.db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(*sql)  # <------
    self.db.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

With your statement

```
sql = "UPDATE product SET created = 1 WHERE skuref = ?",(lastpost,)
```

you have created a tupel like

```
("UPDATE product SET created = 1 WHERE skuref = ?", (lastpost,))
```

You have to give the arguments as parameters to the `execute()` function.

Also your `if` statement is bad: no `:`, `=` instead of `==` and the whole check for True is no nesesary.

Try this:

```
lastpost = record[0]
if created:
    sql = "UPDATE product SET created = 1 WHERE skuref = ?"                
    db.execute(sql, lastpost)
```